# Change external annotations folder in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android-studio

I set the folder for external annotation once in my Android studio. Now, I wanted to change the folder location, following https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-external-annotations.html#d2150916e113 guideline. However, there is no Paths tab...

Does anyone know how to do it? Any config file... whatever!

[image]

Comment: The Android Studio asked me once more so I could change the path. However, the question is still valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to this, https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/02/external-annotations/ I also faced this problem that there is no Paths tab in the Annotations area in the module settings as mentioned in this page.

However, you can edit the .iml in your module folder or .iml in your project folder, depending on whether you want to have externally stored annotations for only a specific module or entire project.

The `annotation-paths` tag is the one you need to edit.
    
`<annotation-paths>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
 </annotation-paths>`

Comment: It seems that my Android Studio stores this information globally, I havent found suggested annotation-paths tag in my *.iml files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can add the tag yourself. Actually, I added the tag and the path myself the second time around.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and the other answer didn't help me -- I couldn't find `<annotation-paths>` anywhere in an `.iml` file and couldn't find a part of the settings gui to change this.

I noticed that Android Studio would ask me to create a new directory tree for annotations from different libraries. So after hunting around, I found that in `<project>/.idea/libraries/<libname>.xml` there are `<ANNOTATIONS>` tags that can  be changed.

For most libraries this worked, however I couldn't find any file or `<ANNOTATIONS>` for the actual classes in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio saves it globally, if you want to change it or remove it, close your Android Studio and follow this:

You can search for `annotationsPath` in

> C:\Users\ USER ACCOUNT NAME \.AndroidStudio3.0\config\options\jdk.table.xml

If using another Android Studio version, look for a similar folder.

Inside the `jdk.table.xml` file, look for it:

```
    <annotationsPath>
      <root type="composite">
        <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/" />
        <root type="simple" url="file://..." />
      </root>
    </annotationsPath>
```

And change the `url="file://...` there, or delete the `<root type="simple" url="file://..." />` line and Android Studio will ask again next time when needed.

Comment: Good catch! For macOS this file will be stored under: `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.2/options/jdk.table.xml` (change the path to reflect the version of Android Studio you use)